# Disable RTS/DSR Handshaking while keeping lines high in PySerial

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I'm using PySerial to read serial messages form a device. The device communicates in TTL. The TTL->RS-232 converter (which is then emulated on its USB input) requires DSR and RTS lines be high to receive power.

So I attempt to send data:

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial(arguments...,rtscts=True,dsrdtr=True)
port.write(b'Hello World)
```

This script will hang forever (or I've never seen it exit). I'm assuming this is because my handshaking lines are dictating I currently can't send a message.

Is there a way to keep my hand shaking lines high, while sending AND receiving messages. I.E.: Bi-directional communication independent of HandShaking

Version Info:

Python3.5 Windows7 Professional x86_64